# Javascript jQuery multiple buttons and click events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am putting something together which has lots of buttons and each button does a different thing.

The way I've done it is like this:

```
$( "#somebutton" ).click(function() { 
    //Do something    
});

$( "#someotherbutton" ).click(function() { 
    //Do something else         
});   

$( "#someotherbutton" ).click(function() { 
    //Do something else         
}); 

$( "#someotherbutton" ).click(function() { 
    //Do something else         
});
```

*...and so one...*

My question is...

Is there a better way to do this for example having an array with button id's and this calling functionsafter the click event?

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you stored the buttons and their corresponding `click` callback functions in an array/object structure, you could compact this and then make a generic function to invoke each at the right time:

```js
$( "button" ).click(function(evt) { 
    // this binding is lost inside of forEach
    var id = this.id;
    // Loop over each stored object in the array...
    var result = buttonsAndFunctions.forEach(function(obj){
      // If the current object.button matches the button.id, invoke the function
      // Since the function won't directly recieve the event, we'll pass the event
      // to the function:
      (obj.button === id) ? obj.fn(evt) : "";
    });
});


var buttonsAndFunctions = [
  // I'm using the same function for each button here only for demonstration
  // In reality, they'd each be different
  { button : "btn1", fn : function(evt){ console.log(evt.target.id + " was clicked"); } },
  { button : "btn2", fn : function(evt){ console.log(evt.target.id + " was clicked"); } },
  { button : "btn3", fn : function(evt){ console.log(evt.target.id + " was clicked"); } },
  { button : "btn4", fn : function(evt){ console.log(evt.target.id + " was clicked"); } }
]
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn1">Button 1</button>
<button id="btn2">Button 2</button>
<button id="btn3">Button 3</button>
<button id="btn4">Button 3</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my projects I use some kind of "convention".
All clickable elements which fires some actions has speciall class, for example "btn-action". This element has "data-action" attribute with information of action to execute.

```
<button class="btn-action" data-action="something" data-mydata="1">click</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
;+function() {

    $('.btn-action').click(function(event) {

        let action = $(this).data('action') 
        if(typeof actions[action] !== undefined) {
            actions[action](event)
        }
    })

    const actions = {

        something : function(e) {
            let button = $(e.currentTarget), 
                mydata = button.data('mydata')
        }, 

        somethingElse : function(e) {

        }
    }
}();
</script>
```

I do not claim that this is the best solution, but this helps me to keep code cleaner.